# Hello World: App instance has no attribute 'say_hi'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just learning python (got five days to do so) and I am having some basic problems with a hello world program. Any idea as to what I am missing?

```
#!/user/bin/python3

from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        def say_hi(self):
            print "Hello word!"

        self.button = Button (frame, text="QUIT",
            fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi = Button (frame, text="Hello",
            command=self.say_hi)
        self.button.pack(side=RIGHT)

root = Tk()
app = App (root)
root.mainloop()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "HelloWorld.py", line 22, in <module>

app = App (root)

File "HelloWorld.py",

line 18, in __init__

command=self.say_hi)

AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'say_hi'
```

Shouldn't `def say_hi(self)`: create the instance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that really how your indentation looks?

Comment: No. Everything after def __init__ is indented properly. Will edit code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you define `say_hi()` inside of `__init__()`.  Just move that down and un-indent it:

```
#!/user/bin/python3

from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button (frame, text="QUIT",
            fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi = Button (frame, text="Hello",
            command=self.say_hi)
        self.button.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "Hello word!"

root = Tk()
app = App (root)
root.mainloop()
```

As it was, `say_hi()` was just a local variable in `__init__()`.  If you define it outside of `__init__()`, it is a method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `say_hi` inside `__init__`'s scope. So it should be:

```
self.hi = Button (frame, text="Hello",
    command=say_hi)
```

But you probably meant:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button (frame, text="QUIT",
            fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi = Button (frame, text="Hello",
            command=self.say_hi)
        self.button.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "Hello word!"
```

Hope this helps!